# What does "quarter" in Arachnid Quarter mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm not very familiar with Hearthstone... This is probably why I don't understand this phrase. The name Arachnid Quarter appears in this article: http://www.pcgamer.com/2014/07/23/hearthstones-curse-of-naxxramas-arachnid-quarter-verdict/

Comment: I guess that it's a group of people or a part of some place.

Comment: [M-W definition 8a](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quarter) ***division** or **district** of a town or city: **he describes the immigrant quarter***

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be one of two possible meanings of the noun **quarter**:

1. A section of a city or a part of a town with a specific flavor, characteristics, e.g. the Chinese Quarter, the French Quarter, etc.
2. A room or chamber, although usually in this sense, it's plural, e.g. the servants quarters.

The adjective **arachnid** is used for anything related to spiders.

Comment: I've found this piece of information: "Naxxramas will open its gates one wing at a time, with a new wing opening each week. The wings of Naxxramas will open in the following order: Arachnid Quarter, Plague Quarter, Military Quarter, Construct Quarter, and Frostwyrm Lair." From: http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/14601010/curse-of-naxxramas%E2%84%A2-wing-entry-details-and-heroic-mode-7-8-2014

Comment: There you are, so they must be sections of a building or town.